# TYPO3 Mask: language labels

Tags: typo3, mask

I try to translate some labels in a mask content element (TYPO3 10). I first created the mask element and mask created a directory "typo3conf/ext/mask_project". I created the file "typo3conf/ext/mask_project/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf" and put a label "read_more" in there.

In my FLUID template ("typo3conf/ext/mask_project/Resources/Private/Mask/Frontend/Templates/Staff.html") I tried:

```
<f:translate key="EXT:mask_project/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:read_more" />
<f:translate key="LLL:EXT:mask_project/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:read_more" />
```

Unfortunately nothing is printed out. Does anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 1):

The `LLL:EXT:...:...` syntax is correct (https://docs.typo3.org/other/typo3/view-helper-reference/10.4/en-us/typo3/fluid/latest/Translate.html) for accessing full paths. For the default file location, you would usually not have to add the whole path (this depends a bit on the FLUIDTEMPLATE configuration). In your case you can also use the ViewHelpers `extensionName=` parameter.

Some hints if you still get no output:

- For new labels to be known, you'll need to clear the system cache.
- https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/10.4/en-us/ApiOverview/Internationalization/XliffApi.html
- https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/book-extbasefluid/master/en-us/9-CrosscuttingConcerns/1-localizing-and-internationalizing-an-extension.html